# Deploying Spring-React-SQL web application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, azure, rest

I would like to make web application based on Spring REST with SQL db and React frontend.

While it's OK for me, to deploy it locally, I don't really know, how to make it visible on public website. I thought of Azure, AWS, Google Cloud, but I cannot find any sufficient information.

Should I run frontend and backend on two independent Web apps? If so, how would I make them communicate?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can start your Backend as a Spring Boot Application on any standard port available. [default is 8080].

Same can be looked up by your React Frontend using `process.env.API_URL`.

Below article from DZone is a rich source of information.

https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-spring-boot-and-react-with-spring-secu-1

Also to achieve the same, you can try a simple combination of AWS EC2 & RDS combination to start with and enhance it as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS cloud, You can make it public using aws cloudfront which serves static content from s3. You just need to upload your react build on s3 and you can host via cloudfront.

For your spring rest service you can deploy your .war Or .jar on AWS Elastic beanstalk(EBS).

Your database should be on AWS RDS

Using those service you can ealsy host your website with react frontend, spring rest services and database handling

Comment: Do you have some examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use have to configure CloudFront with your s3 bucket
https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/host-ember-application-in-aws-s3-using-cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

1. Front-end will make REST API calls to your backend to fetch/retrieve or to send data. This is usually the way frontend communicates with backend.
2. In order to make your applications accessible to the public over internet, you will need an external IP address.
3. Your backend and frontend applications may use the same IP but different port and access paths.
4. You might also need to have a domain name and DNS setup against your ip.
5. Backend will be deployed independently of frontend and you can have both of them running on same machine.